# Why am i getting a blank UI in filedepot module in drupal 7?

Tags: files

I want to have proper file management for my site powered by drupal. I have downloaded the filedepot module, and have performed all the steps to configure it properly...but still i am not getting the user interface after i click the filedepot link on the navigation menu, its totally blank. i figured out there are many, who are getting the same problem; have tried different solutions, but no luck anywhere.

please suggest me some solution for the same, m using drupal 7, filedepot 7.x-1.1 and libraries 7.x.-1.0.

please please need help badly

Comment: If you're getting a white screen, turn on PHP debugging so that you can see what the error message is.  If this is a module bug, it should be reported on the module's issue queue.

Comment: Have you checked whether YUI libraries are loading properly ?

Comment: @mohit_rocks how do i check whether yui libraries are loading properly??

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution at "https://drupal.org/node/1268336"

Renaming it solved the issue for me.

"rename /sites/all/libraries/jquery.blockUI.js to /sites/all/libraries/jquery.blockui.js. It is case-sensitive, and the JS file is not being loaded after following the instructions provided."

Comment: Tried this, still hangs on load.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Diagnostic Tools](http://drupal.org/project/dtools) as shown in [this article](http://drupal.org/node/482956) - it describes most of common White Screen of Death causes and how to identify them. Server's error.log would be handy too.